# Https alternative port for 443

Tags: https, portforwarding, ports

I have two raspberry pi and I have two different services on every.

In one case I have open port for 443 (https). I would like to have the (https) on second machine. Is there any alternative port for 443, or I can set any I want?

Also is there any alternative port for 80?

I have two heavy (for rpi:D ) services on each, that is why I want to have alternative ports opened.

Is there any regularity I should follow?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you setup your rpi to serve https on two different ports (which you can do in the daemons config), then you can access both easily :

The one on the default port can be accessed simply with `https://hostname/` or  `https://ip-address/`, whereas the one on the specific port can be accessed by specifying the port, for example : `https://hostname:444/`

(Same goes for http on port 80)

Comment: so, the rule is: increment by 1 to standard port? Like 80 > 81, 443 > 444 . Tnx

Comment: That's your choice : 444 was just an example :) Suggestion is to chose something close to the original port to hint at the service nature, but it's not technically mandatory.